# How do I create tables with the same formatting as a state transition table?

Tags: tables

For instance:

[image: A state transition table]

I'm total Latex noob so I cannot provide a MWE.

Comment: Welcome. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{r||l|l}
 & 0 & 1\\
 \hline\hline
 \to q_0 & q_2 & q_0\\
 * q_1 & q_1 & q_1\\
 q_2 & q_2 & q_1\\
\end{array}\]
\end{document}`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This specific table was made using [`hhline`](//ctan.org/pkg/hhline):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ r || c | c }
    & 0 & 1 \\
    \hhline{===}
    \rightarrow q_0 & q_2 & q_0 \\
    \relax    * q_1 & q_1 & q_1 \\
                q_2 & q_2 & q_1
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```